# How to center an image used as Grid Background through C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set a Grid's backgroud through code.
The Grid has 1000 x 1000 size, the same size of the loaded PNG.
I load this PNG into a Stream, then execute the following code:

```
using (StreamWrapper wrapper = new StreamWrapper(streamImg))
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(wrapper))
{
    originalImage = new BitmapImage();
    originalImage.BeginInit();
    originalImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    originalImage.StreamSource = reader.BaseStream;
    originalImage.EndInit();
    originalImage.Freeze();
}
ib = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = ConvertToGrayScale(ref originalImage) };
grdQuebraCabeça.Background = ib;


private FormatConvertedBitmap ConvertToGrayScale(ref BitmapImage image)
{
    FormatConvertedBitmap grayImage = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
    grayImage.BeginInit();
    grayImage.Source = image;
    grayImage.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray32Float;
    grayImage.EndInit();
    return grayImage;
}
```

The following screenshot is the result:
[image: Result of above code on WPF]

You can see black blocks on lower and right sides.
I want to center the image in the grid.
Is that possible? How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Tried changing line 11 to:

`ib = new ImageBrush() { ImageSource = ConvertToGrayScale(ref originalImage), Stretch = Stretch.None, AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Center, AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center, TileMode = TileMode.None };`

The black boxes reduced by half with `Stretch = Stretch.None`.

Comment: Found out that, if I use originalImage as ImageSource, the image fills the Grid... but I want it converted to grayscale.